# Hugo exclude file types from page bundle?

Tags: filter, types, static, publish, hugo

I'm generating a static website with Hugo.

Here's the structure of my content folder:

```
content/
└── post
    ├── post01
    │   ├── image.xcf
    │   ├── image.jpg
    │   └── index.md
    └── post02
        ├── image.xcf
        ├── image.jpg
        └── index.md
```

Each of the posts has a **.jpg** files. These images are exported from my image editing program. To avoid confusion, I'm keeping the original working **.xcf** files from the image editing program in the same folder as the exported image, in case I need to edit an image in the future, and re-export it. But I don't want to publish those **.xcf** files to the server.

Is there a way to configure Hugo to exclude all files with **.xcf** extension when generating the static site?

Answer (score 4):

> Be aware that there's an [open issue at GitHub](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/4874) that this feature might not work exactly as documented. It worked for me with Hugo 0.62.0 and your given directory and file structure.

As [per the documentation](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/#ignore-content-files-when-rendering), you can exclude content files with the `ignoreFiles` directive.

In your specific case, add the following to your `config.toml` (resp. YAML or JSON)

```
ignoreFiles = [ "\\.xcf$" ]
```